# why is data not showing after onload parameter CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

When I send data from this form the data is sent to the database but the problem is that when I try to visualize the boxes in a refresh of page as they should be getting the data back (after saving previous changes) and apearing as 'checked' but they are not.

the values are being sent back (1,0) but are not showing where they are supposed  to effects of turning into a different color as 'checked' are not.

on the body tag I have

```
<body onload="colores();">
```

that runs the function colores() in the snippet

I tried to do this:

```
var str1 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_a?>';
var str2 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_b?>';
var str3 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_c?>';
var str4 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_d?>';

if(str1 == 0){
    str1.style.background= '#fff';
    str1.style.color='#fff';
    str1.value=0;
}else if(str1 == 1){
    str1.style.background= '#000';
    str1.style.color='#000';
    str1.value=1;
}
```

in the colores function

```js
function color(campo){
 valor_campo = document.getElementById(campo).value;
 if(valor_campo== 0){
 document.getElementById(campo).style.background= '#000';
 document.getElementById(campo).style.color='#000';
 document.getElementById(campo).value=1;
 }else if(valor_campo == 1){
 document.getElementById(campo).style.background= '#fff';
 document.getElementById(campo).style.color='#fff';
 document.getElementById(campo).value=0;
 }
}

function colores(){

 if(document.getElementById('cc11_a').value == 0){
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').style.background= '#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').style.color='#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').value=0;
 }else if(document.getElementById('cc11_a').value == 1){
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').style.background= '#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').style.color='#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_a').value=1;
 }

 if(document.getElementById('cc11_b').value == 0){
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').style.background= '#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').style.color='#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').value=0;
 }else if(document.getElementById('cc11_b').value == 1){
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').style.background= '#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').style.color='#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_b').value=1;
 }

 if(document.getElementById('cc11_c').value == 0){
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').style.background= '#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').style.color='#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').value=0;
 }else if(document.getElementById('cc11_c').value == 1){
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').style.background= '#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').style.color='#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_c').value=1;
 }

 if(document.getElementById('cc11_d').value == 0){
 document.getElementById('cc11_d').style.background= '#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_d').style.color='#fff';
 document.getElementById('cc11_').value=0;
 }else if(document.getElementById('cc11_d').value == 1){
 document.getElementById('cc11_d').style.background= '#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_d').style.color='#000';
 document.getElementById('cc11_d').value=1;
 }

}
```

```html
<td colspan="3" style="text-align:left">

            <input name="cc11_a" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_a" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
            <input name="cc11_b" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_b" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
            <input name="cc11_c" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_c" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
            <input name="cc11_d" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_d" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />

            </td>
```

Comment: the values are there but you cannot see them.Double-click the fields to see them.

Comment: the problem is that the data is not being showed after refresh with the data that was saved beforehand. if I checked one box when I refresh the box should show checked. @PedroLobito

Comment: that is why I load the function colores to check the ones that have a '1' in its value